Some photos downloaded from iCloud cannot be attached to email
I can upload around 20 photos from my phone to iCloud, and a short while later they are shown in Photos on my Mac. All seems good.
If I try to attach these photos to an email I'm writing in Mail most of them are not shown in the Finder uploader window. I can see a few of the photos but not all of them. Yet as I say, they are quite happily visible in Photos.
Things I've checked:

Local disk space is fine (33GB used out of 121)
iCloud photos are automatically downloaded by Photos on demand (as expected)
Mac version is Monterey 12.7.6 (the problem isn't repeatable on another Mac running the ancient Big Sur. I don't think either can be upgraded further)
It doesn't appear to be a JPEG vs HEIC issue
The same issue occurs if I try to upload photos to a website (I would conclude, therefore, it's not specifically Mail that's at fault)
The missing photos aren't abnormally large (but perhaps there's a small limit setting I don't know about)

What else should I check to try and ensure that any of the photos that are visible in Photos can be selected for attaching to an email in Mail?
